# How do a setup with HSQLDB in-memory database for executing Junit test suite for a Maven project?

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, hsqldb

Working in a Maven project developed in Spring, Hibernate, MySQL etc.
I have to migrate from MySQL Database to HSQLSB database for Junit test suite execution during maven build. Please share the steps to be performed.

Comment: Hi! What did you try? Show some code to us :)

Answer (score 0):

Use spring profiles and create the DataSources with properties injected from property files.